# Stuck when opening a SSH tunnel with Remmina for VNC connection

Tags: ssh, vnc, ssh-tunnel, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have five *x11vnc* servers and all of them embed a *ssh* server.

The five servers have the same *ssh* and *x11vnc* configurations.

Since a couple of days, I cannot connect anymore to the *x11vnc* server of a **single** machine with *Remmina* (the fourth ones work correctly).

I use *Remmina* as *VNC* client with a *ssh* tunnel to secure the connection.

When opening the connection, the pop-up *Connecting to [server] through ssh tunnel...* remains indefinitely on the screen.

However, **I do not face any problem if**:

- I do not use the *ssh* tunnel,
- I manually *ssh* to the server,
- I build a local *ssh* tunnel manually.

I cannot understand why it does not work anymore and why the 4 other servers run perfectly well.

Any idea?

Following the server's `dmesg` log when connecting (I replaced the username by **username** and the hostname (specified in my `/etc/hosts` file) by **custom_hostname**:

```
Jan 11 14:36:11 UC-79 sshd[4346]: Accepted publickey for username from 192.168.1.211 port 50068 ssh2: RSA SHA256:rMn
4ArMNfrLrFP53vdW5TrwpzHIm08xCqDQRJzqaW98
Jan 11 14:36:11 UC-79 sshd[4346]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Jan 11 14:36:11 UC-79 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Jan 11 14:36:11 UC-79 systemd-logind[648]: New session 55 of user username.
Jan 11 14:36:12 UC-79 sshd[4423]: error: connect_to custom_hostname port 5900: failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of the crash when *Remmina* attempted to establish the *ssh* tunnel.

The problem was the **hostname** I manually set in the `/etc/hosts` files of both the client and the server.

Sometimes in my company, some IP addresses are reallocated (DHCP) and I have to manually update my `hosts` files with my custom hostnames. This time I missed an update and the same host name was pointing to a different IP (invalid at the server side), that's why the *ssh* process couldn't locally create the tunnel after establishing connection.

Fixing the IP address in the hosts file solved the problem!

I could find it by manually read *ssh* logs with the following command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p [custom-port]`
```

Then using a custom *Remmina* configuration using a *ssh* tunnel pointing to that debug *ssh* server.